# Running a filter from console for inspecting value

Tags: angularjs, batarang

Is there any way to run a $filter in console using inspector? Using batarang I can get the scope attached to a specific element, but I want to run a general filter on the values in scope, how can I do it?

Comment: This is a better answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399331/how-can-i-access-and-test-an-angularjs-filter-from-the-browser-console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know your usecase, but if it's **only for debugging** you could make the $filter available globally.

Just inject the $filter in some controller or whatever and move it to the **window**

```
app.controller( 'MainCtrl',
  function (  $filter )
  {
     window.$filterForDebugging = $filter;
  });
```

Now you can use

```
window.$filterForDebugging('date')(new Date(), 'medium');
// "27.08.2015 09:09:49"
```