# How can I access and test an AngularJS filter from the browser console?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angularjs-filter

Given a test filter, say this ['capitalize' filter](http://michaeltempest.com/unit-testing-angular-filter-with-jasmine/) that will capitalize the first letter of each word:

```
return function (input) {
  return (!!input) ? input.replace(/([^\W_]+[^\s-]*) */g, function (txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  }) : '';
}
```

How can this filter be tested from a browser's JavaScript console?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Filters can be called in HTML template binding {{myString | capitalize}}, but to gain access to it in the browser we have an excellent option.  Consider this:

`$filter('filter')(array, expression, comparator)` per [Angular $filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Realizing a filter can be called via the`$filter` service, you can thus access, call and test the `capitalize` filter this way:

`angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$filter')('capitalize')('capitalization test')`

The result in the console?  `"Capitalization Test"`

What about a filter with more than one input?  Just add the parameter, for instance if the `capitalize` filter had a second boolean parameter to restrict capitalization to the first word only:

`angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$filter')('capitalize')('capitalization test', true)`

OR

`angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$filter')('capitalize').apply(null, ['capitalization test', true])`

Kudos to this SO article and related blog entries for posting on accessing services from the console: [access service from console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527832/how-can-i-test-an-angularjs-service-from-the-console).

Comment: This will only work if debug mode is enabled.  If it is disabled, you can do angular.reloadWithDebugInfo().

Comment: @ryanm Thanks a lot for this.It really saved a lot of my time and was such an easy tip.

Comment: @crackerplace My pleasure!  Glad you found it helpful.